# adapt vim configs to nvidia-docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vim, bundle, nvidia-docker

I am using nvidia-docker to train few deep learning models. Every time I attach to my running container I realised, vim settings are not adapting into container's vim. 
So I installed vundle, and copied host's `.vimrc` options to containers `root/.vimrc`.

I don't have specific error. But :NERDTree or other commands are not running please help.

Here is my `.vimrc` settings

```
set shell=/bin/bash
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
   filetype off                  " required

   " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
   set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
   call vundle#begin()
   " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
   "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

   " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
   Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

   " The following are examples of different formats supported.
   " Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
   " plugin on GitHub repo
   Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
   " plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
   " Plugin 'L9'
   " Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
   Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
   " git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
   " Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
   " The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
   " Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
   Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
   " Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
   " different version somewhere else.
   " Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

   " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
   call vundle#end()            " required
   filetype plugin indent on    " required
   " To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
   "filetype plugin on
   "
   " Brief help
   " :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
   " :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
   " :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
   " :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
   "
   " see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
   " Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:  2016 Mar 25
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup        " keep a backup file (restore to previous version)
  set undofile      " keep an undo file (undo changes after closing)
endif
set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
set incsearch       " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
" so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

" In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")

" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
" Only define it when not defined already.
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif

if has('langmap') && exists('+langnoremap')
  " Prevent that the langmap option applies to characters that result from a
  " mapping.  If unset (default), this may break plugins (but it's backward
  " compatible).
  set langnoremap
endif


" Add optional packages.
"
" The matchit plugin makes the % command work better, but it is not backwards
" compatible.
packadd matchit
" execute pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin indent on
set number
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
```

[Result of :PluginInstall "Done!" screenshot inside container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNOVI.png)

Additional detail: Installed NERDTree inside docker using git clone

`cd .vim/bundle/`

`git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git`

Comment: There's no NERDTree in that `vimrc`.

Comment: okay i'll try adding `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree`

Comment: got error `E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree`

Comment: @romainl  what should I add in vimrc?

Comment: NERDTree is a plugin. You don't install that plugin so why do you expect a command provided by that plugin to do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used `apt-vim` to install nerdtree. Worked well for me

[apt-vim](https://github.com/egalpin/apt-vim)

Installed apt-vim manually